# React Native onPress fuction is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on some project with book information showing. I've successfully got the data from server and wanted to make modal pop and disappear with the onPress function. but it is not working. modal shows, but not disappering.

I've tried putting this.togglePopoff.bind(this) in constructor but it did't work.
I also check the log with console.log("I'm pressing button") inside function 'togglePopoff' but the log didn't show also.

this is my constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentDate: new Date(),
        markedDate: moment(new Date()).format(),
        isPopVisible: false,
        apiData: [],
        activeSwitch: 1,
    }
    this.ISBN = null;
    this.book_name = null;
    this.img_src = null;
    this.author = null;
    this.publisher = null;
    this.public_date = null;
    this.more_url = null;
    this.read_rate = null;
    this.read_date = null;
    this.category = null;
    this.best = null;
    this.togglePopoff = this.togglePopoff.bind(this);
}
```

this is my functions to disappear modal.

```
togglePopoff = () => {
    this.setState({ isPopVisible: false });
}
saveBook = () => {
    this.setState({ isPopVisible: false });

}
```

and this is my searchBook function.

```
searchBook = () => {
    this.setState({ isPopVisible: true });
    // popup - onoff
    if(this.ISBN == null){
        this.setState({ isPopVisible: false});
        alert("please input ISBN code");
        //return 0;
    }
    else {

    fetch('http://220.149.242.12:10001/search/book/' + (this.ISBN), {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((responseData) => {
        return responseData.json();
    }).then((jsonData) => {
        console.log(jsonData);
        this.setState({ apiData: jsonData })
        console.log(this.state.apiData)
    }).done();
    this.ISBN = null;
    this.book_name = null;
    this.img_src = null;
    this.author = null;
    this.publisher = null;
    this.public_date = null;
    this.more_url = null;
    this.read_rate = null;
    this.read_date = null;
    this.category = null;
    this.best = null;
    };
}
```

and this is where onPress goes.

```
render() {
    const data = this.state.apiData;
    const today = this.state.currentDate;
    var dataDisplay = null;
    if (data && data.items) {
        dataDisplay = data.items.map(function (item) {
            //var image = "'" + item.image + "'";
            var image = item.image;
            console.log(image);
            return (
                <View key={item.user_name} style={styles.popfirst}>
                    <View style={styles.popsecond}>
                        <View style={styles.popthird}>
                            <View style={{ paddingTop: 30, }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: '#52C8B2', fontSize: 20, }}>book information</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ paddingTop: 20, }}>
                                <Image style={{ height: 250, width: 150,  resizeMode: 'contain', }}
                                    source={{ uri: image }}>
                                </Image>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ paddingTop: 10, }}>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, }}>{item.title}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ paddingTop: 10, }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: '#D7D7D7' }}>{item.author} | {item.publisher} | {item.pubdate}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.popbtn}>
                                <View style={{ width: 10, }}></View>
                                <View style={styles.popbtnleft}>
                                    <SwitchButton
                                        onValueChange={(val) => this.activeSwitch(val)} 
                                        text1='reading'
                                        text2='done'
                                        switchWidth={120}
                                        switchHeight={30}
                                        switchdirection='ltr'
                                        switchBorderRadius={0}
                                        switchSpeedChange={500}
                                        switchBorderColor='#52C8B2'
                                        switchBackgroundColor='#F2F2F2'
                                        btnBorderColor='#52C8B2'
                                        btnBackgroundColor='#52C8B2'
                                        fontcolor='#333'
                                        activeFontColor='#FFF'
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.popbtnbig}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bigbtn} onPress={this.togglePopoff}><Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#FFF' }}>cancle</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bigbtn} onPress={this.saveBook}><Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#FFF' }}>save</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        });
    };
    return (
        <View style={cstyle.greycontainer}>
            <View style={styles.firstbox}>
                <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', fontSize: 20 }}>input ISBN code</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.secondbox}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    placeholder="Enter ISBN"
                    onChangeText={(text) => { this.ISBN = text }}
                    value={this.ISBN}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.searchbtn} onPress={this.searchBook}>
                    <IonIcon name="ios-search" size={30} color='#FFF' />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.firstbox}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.greenbtn}>
                    <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', fontSize: 20 }}>cancle</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.isPopVisible}>
                {dataDisplay}
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );

}
}
```

how can I make the modal off?

Answer (score 1):

> `this.togglePopoff = this.togglePopoff.bind(this);`
>
> As you are already using arrow function, so you need not to bind your function. bind method is already present in arrow functions.

```
togglePopoff = () => {
    this.setState({ isPopVisible: false });
}
```

this is correct, just remove the bind method from constructor.

Comment: I removed it but still not working... maybe it is because of the isVisible in Modal tag?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Try to bind all Your functions in `constructor` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentDate: new Date(),
        markedDate: moment(new Date()).format(),
        isPopVisible: false,
        apiData: [],
        activeSwitch: 1,
    }
    this.ISBN = null;
    this.book_name = null;
    this.img_src = null;
    this.author = null;
    this.publisher = null;
    this.public_date = null;
    this.more_url = null;
    this.read_rate = null;
    this.read_date = null;
    this.category = null;
    this.best = null;
    this.togglePopoff = this.togglePopoff.bind(this);
    this.saveBook = this.saveBook.bind(this);
}
```

Create Your functions like this:

```
togglePopoff(){
    this.setState({ isPopVisible: false });
}
saveBook(){
    this.setState({ isPopVisible: false });
}
```

And call them like this:

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bigbtn} onPress={() => this.togglePopoff()}><Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#FFF' }}>cancle</Text></TouchableOpacity>
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bigbtn} onPress={() => this.saveBook()}><Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#FFF' }}>save</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: it seams onPress is working but got on error that " this2.toogglePopoff is not a function. (In '_this2.togglePopoff().','_this2.togglePopoff' is undefined) "

Comment: So now it want to do something but gives an error? Am I understand right?

Comment: um...yes I think onPress started to call the function. but the function got error. I put console.log("working function") inside of the togglePopoff function but log is not showing and gives an error.

Comment: Okay, what about now?

Comment: sorry.. but I don't understand what you said about apiData. Why apiData got a empty array? I put console.log(data) and console.log(data.items) inside render() before if(data && data.items) and got full data at last render()..

Comment: Okay sorry. That was some complicated and kind of silly options. Now I tried one more option. I hope it will finally help You :)

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply but it is also not working ... still getting a same error :(

Comment: I solved it!!!!! I change the "dataDisplay = data.items.map(function (item) " into "dataDisplay = data.items.map(item=>{}" and it's working!! Thank you soooo much for your kind replies! :D Have a great day!!

Comment: Oh thats very good, that was an interesting question, well done!